# move control to newly opened IE window in selenium webdriver (using python) :no window name , no window handle ,not a alert

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, window-handles

Setup :python bindings for selenium 2.45.0 ,IEserver driver2.45.0(x86),python 2.7.9 ,window 7 64 bit

Issue : when i click on this redirect button   href= https:www.work.test.co.in:1XXX9/TEST/servlet/MainServlet/home" target="_blank"

a new window opens , unable to click anything on new window as control(focus) remains on previous window (confirmed by closing the previous window).

Tried
1.no name , so cannot try

```
driver.switch_to_window("windowName")
```

2.tried to print the handle (so that i can use handle reference ) but i can see only one window handle .  used following code

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
  print "Handle arr = ",handle
  driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

3.Question1 : why i am getting only one window handle handle , i can see two IE instances in task manager.

4.i tried using  index - 0 ,1 etc.

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

5.not sure of this thing though tried

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last())
```

6.tried though i am sure that its not an alert window .

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

SCRIPT :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep  



driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get("https://my intranet site .aspx")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("my xpath ")
elem.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab1_2']/div[16]")
elem.click()

handle = driver.current_window_handle
print "Handle main  = ",handle

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("page link button")
elem.click()
sleep(5)
my tried scenarioes here
```

Suggestions will be highly appreciated 
Update - when new window opened directly through link URL  , able to perform actions on it like clicking etc
So only issue is when I open it in continuation of first window through script.

Update : Main concern is why not getting second window handle even if task manager showing two instances of IE .

Comment: The second solution that you have written is generally the way that most people are able to switch windows. I would ask you two things to troubleshoot. First, encapsulate the solution you have written into a while loop that goes 100 iterations with a 100ms sleep and print the number of windows to the console. See if it ever reaches 2 windows. Second, typically there is a conditional statement before the `driver.switch_to_window(handle)` which states `if(handle != parent_window_handle)` so that you don't end up switching back to your original window.

Comment: 1.Tried it under 100 loop ,1ms gap , it always print only one window handle      2. second point is secondary , i m trying to get the second window handle first , though will be including in code to avoid ending up on parent window  3.Thanks for the reply

Comment: Is Protected Mode settings are updated to same level?

Comment: Surya , are you referring to  proteceted mode setting in IE , if yes , then , both windows are a part of intranet site , I have following settings in IE governed by admin . internet - medium protected , intranet - not protected , trusted sites - not protected , restricted sites -highly protected. Please pardon me if i am wrong or mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but in Java I would do it in this way:

```
 // get handles to all opened windows before the click
 Set<String>  handlesBeforeTheClick = driver.getWindowHandles();
 // and now click on the link that opens a new window
 findElement( linkThatOpensNewWindow ).click();
 // then wait until a new window will be opened
 wait.until( ....condition ==> handlesBeforeClick.size() < driver.getWindowHandles().size(); .... )
 // then get a handle to a new window
 Set<String> handlesAfterClick = driver.getWindowHandles();
 handlesAfterClick.removeAll( handlesBeforeClick );
 String handleToNewWindow = handlesAfterClick.iterator().next();
```

Comment: i think i have tried the python version of this solution . thanks for reply